# Overriding Strapi default datetime format?

Tags: java, datetime, strapi

I have a string of a datetime that is formatted like this:
`"1987-04-01T00:00:00Z"`

This field is part of an object along with other fields that are daily checked for any updates against currently stored Strapi model. If the incoming objects are not equal, the object is updated on the Strapi side. However, in the Strapi model, the field is type "datetime" and is then formatted and stored in this format:
`1987-04-01T00:00:00.000Z`

This is an issue because when the Java .equals() method checks for equality, the two will never be equal, causing unnecessary updates on an otherwise equal object.

Is it possible to overwrite Strapi's default format for datetime to not store the unnecessary milliseconds and match the format? Or is this not an option and better to pre-format on Java side to match how Strapi stores it?

Comment: You want to convert both to something more reliable like timestamp and check on timestamps

Comment: FYI, Strapi datetime format is the JavaScript ISO format. Maybe you can find a way to have the iso format in Java and check the equality.